# Want to delete multiple duplicate fields

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, delete

I have a feature class which contains duplicate fields like a,b,c,a1,b1,c1. I want to delete these duplicate fields. The number of fields is more than 100. So instead of manual deletion I am looking for some automation.

Comment: Always duplicate only by first letter? Which field do you want to keep of the duplicates, the first?

Answer (score 2):

This will delete duplicates by first letter (a1 is a duplicate of a2, a3, aksadjldj etc.) and keep the first occurence of the field. Backup your data Before you try it!:

```
import arcpy, collections
from operator import itemgetter

fc = r'C:\database.gdb\featureclass' #Change to match your data

all_fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if f.type not in ('Geometry','OID')] #List all fields by name
first_letter = [f[0] for f in all_fields] #List only by first letter of field name
fields_to_delete=[]

#Create a dictionary of starting letters and all their indexes. For example {a:[1,2,3,4]}
duplicates = collections.defaultdict(list)
for index, item in enumerate(first_letter):
    duplicates[item].append(index)

#If more than one value per key in dictionary append field names to delete list
for key, value in duplicates.iteritems():
    if len(value)>1:
        fields_to_delete.append(itemgetter(*value[1:])(all_fields))  

arcpy.DeleteField_management(in_table=fc, drop_field=fields_to_delete)
```

Comment: Nice code and comprehensive.